# Error 1 error C2678: binary '!=' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::ofstream' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Tags: c++, binary

I am getting this error with debug or release

> > Error    1   error C2678: binary '!=' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::ofstream' (or there is no acceptable conversion) c:\users\yuser\desktop\injector\injector\WriteLog.h 27  1   Injector

Can any help me how to fix this

Code `Writelog.h`

```
#include <windows.h> 
#include <tlhelp32.h> 
#include <shlwapi.h> 
#include <conio.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <iostream>

#pragma warning(disable:4996)


using namespace std;


ofstream ofile;
char dlldir[320];
char LogFileName[20] = "Log.txt"; //Change this if you want

char *GetDirectoryFile(char *filename){
    static char path[320];
    strcpy(path, dlldir);
    strcat(path, filename);
    return path;
}

void WriteLog(const char *fmt, ...){
    if (ofile != NULL) <<< Problem is here on( ! ) gives error 
    {
        if (!fmt) { return; }
        va_list va_alist;
        char logbuf[256] = { 0 };
        va_start(va_alist, fmt);
        _vsnprintf(logbuf + strlen(logbuf), sizeof(logbuf) - strlen(logbuf), fmt, va_alist);
        va_end(va_alist);
        ofile << logbuf << endl;
    }
}


void logstart(HMODULE hDll){
    GetModuleFileName(hDll, dlldir, 512);
    for (int i = strlen(dlldir); i > 0; i--) { if (dlldir[i] == '\\') { dlldir[i + 1] = 0; break; } }
    ofile.open(GetDirectoryFile(LogFileName), ios::app);
}
```

Comment: Question is clearly off-topic.

Answer (score 5):

The line

```
if (ofile != NULL)
```

was valid in C++03, but is not valid in C++11. Use simply

```
if (ofile)
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of checking NULL

you can check like this

```
if(ofile.bad() != TRUE)
{
   //Do Stuff
}
```